# Go Webserver Not Handling POST Requests

Tags: http, post, go, webserver

I'm creating a simple web server using Go's http package. I'm registering just one handler, for requests to the path "/requests/".

It can handle GET requests just fine but when I send a POST request, the handler is never invoked and the client gets a 301 Moved Permanently response.

I've tried searching for this but it appears this isn't a problem people are commonly facing.

My handler is:

```
func requestHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello")
}
```

main function:

```
func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/requests/", requestHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", mux)
}
```

Curl gives the following output:

```
>> curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8000/requests
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /requests/
Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2017 08:51:10 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Go's own http client returns a similar response object:

```
 &{301 Moved Permanently 301 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-Type:[text/plain; charset=utf-8] Location:[/requests/] Date:[Thu, 12 Jan 2017 08:51:58 GMT] Content-Length:[0]] 0x339190 0 [] false false map[] 0xc4200cc0f0 <nil>}
```

Again, GET requests behave just as I'd expect them to and invoke the handler function. Do I need to do something differently to handle POST requests? Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: Your path is `/requests/`, not `/requests`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are querying for `/requests`.

The redirect is pointing you to `/requests/`

You used curl like this :

`curl localhost:8000/requests`

You need to either use `/requests` instead of `/requests/` in `mux.HandleFunc`.

or use

`curl localhost:8000/requests/`

Also note that if you request would work on a browser without any change as it handles redirects automatically.

And the route with trailing slash would return 404, if the route in mux.HandleFunc does not have a trailing slash.

PS : Your `requestHandler` handles all methods, not just `POST` requests. You need to check for `r.Method` to handle the methods differently.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll have to be more mindful of trailing slashes.

Comment: @beruuu, Please take your time to understand that URLs with and without the trailing slash are semantically different with regard to accessing to the resources they represent. Consider starting with [this document](http://sebastians-pamphlets.com/thou-must-not-steal-the-trailing-slash-from-my-urls/).